# How to insert result of mysql_real_escape_string() into oracle database?

Tags: mysql, oracle, insert, quotes, apostrophe

For inserting special characters in data like (,')etc., I am using mysql_real_escape_string() function & it's working fine.

Now I want to use same variable while inserting values in Oracle.

```
$str = 'N.G.Palace\'s Building',
    'xyzcity', '12345678','India','100001',12
```

Here $str is result of mysql_real_escape_string(). so it escapes special character.
Now my code for oracle is like this-:

```
 $qry ="INSERT INTO Ora_table(ship_to_street, ship_to_city,ship_to_country, ship_to_telephone, order_id, record_no) VALUES(".$str);
```

So my doubt is Oracle is not accepting values return by mysql_real_escape_string i.e. Palace\'s (like this as this mysql function attach \ before 'single quote)?
So can anybody tell me ho9w can I use that variable $str to insert data into Oracle?

Also I tried like this also-:

```
"q"."'"."c".$str."c"."'"
```

can we use this for multiple values like in my case...though still I am unable
to inser data in oracle?

```
HOW to insert special characters in Oracle db?
like 'SWEET/HOME', 'CROY-BOY' etc. /,-,\ etc.
```

please tell me..

Comment: Why would you ever a MySQL escaping function when building a SQL query for an oracle database?!

Comment: Bcz, I am first inserting data into Mysql database & using same variable to insert into Oracle through PHP.

Comment: When you read the data back from  your MySQL database you'll have the original string without any escaping - remember, escaping is done so the query does not break; or to say it in pseudocode: `select(insert(escape(str))) == str`

Comment: ok...But my doubt is how to handle single quote problem e.g-('N.G.Palace's Building','xyzcity', '12345678','India','100001',12) Now look at the first value...How it will interpret that N.G.Palace's Building is only one value...as there is single quote in Palace's so thats why I am unable to insert data into oracle.

Comment: Well when insertint it to your oracle DB you need to escape it again using the appropriate function from the php oracle bindings. **Or do it like @BobJarvis suggested and properly separate query and data!**

Comment: What Bob Jarvis said - I'd vote it up 100 times if I could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly urge you not to build queries by appending strings together.  This is a ticket straight to hell - or to SQL Injection City, which is one stop earlier.  :-)  Seriously, though, if you use parameter markers and bind the values to the parameter markers you gain a couple of advantages:

1. You don't have to escape anything, and
2. No worries about SQL injection.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score -2):

From: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php#94758

```
function no_magic_quotes($query) {

        $data = explode("\\",$query);
        $cleaned = implode("",$data);
        return $cleaned;
}

// I'm using mysql_escape_string as a simple example, but this function would work for any escaped string.
$query = "It's amazing! Who's to say this isn't a simple function?";
$badstring = mysql_escape_string($query);

echo '<b>Without function:</b> '.$badstring;
echo '<br><br>';
echo '<b>With function:</b> '.no_magic_quotes($badstring);
```